# Remove autolayout (constraints) in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to make my project compatible with Snow Leopard and I am not able to remove the autolayout in the nibs using Interface builder (XCode 4.3 on Lion).

Is it possible to remove the constraints and the autolayout in a nib on XCode?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Go to the File inspector in interface builder, and untick "Use Auto Layout".

Comment: This works just as well to maintain compatibility for pre-iOS 6 devices using interface builder. Thanks!

Comment: I had to remove the "Use Auto Layout" to enable affine transformations working on an UIView inherited object. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Great! The File inspector is the first tab on right inspector. You have File, Quick Help, Identity, Attributes, Size and Connections.

Comment: I found that by also removing 'Autoresize subviews' helped me with my sizing and positioning of objects.

Comment: autoresize subviews is great if you DO want to work with constraints (which are actually useful if you get used to working with them) but don't want interface builder to override your constrainsts when you move anything.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Go to the file inspector and uncheck the option 'Use Autolayout' below Document versioning.

Comment: A picture tells more than 1000 words!

Comment: Yes, the picture is better than the text in the selected answer, but this is the same solution, and it is posted more than a year later. Too bad that the two answers are not merged and the rep points shared :-)