# How do I make the pop up button taller in Xcode?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

When creating a desktop application, I have created a `Pop Up Button` using interface builder:

[image]
[image]

However, when I go on size inspector, the box for changing the height is greyed out:

[image]

Even if I change the font, the button itself won't get any bigger:

[image]

What should I do if I want a taller `Pop Up Button`?

Comment: Have you tried setting its height in the code?  In the code try `CGRect rect = popup.frame;` frame.size.height = newHeight; [popup setFrame: rect];`

Comment: @AleksG I've just tried that right now, and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder) answer, I'm not on a Mac right now so I can't test it, but I think it is related with the auto layout settings and the constraints.

Comment: I just tried it. but it looks like even after unchecking autolayout, the height option is still greyed out.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm trying to do this right now myself, without much luck.