# How do you disable the NSConstraint in ios6 Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, autosize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove autolayout (constraints) in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder)

I am creating an app and I don't want the NSConstraints to be enabled because they are moving stuff in the UIViewController when I run the app.

Is there any way that I can disable them? Maybe a bit of code in each View Controller or just a setting.

Comment: that is for snow leopard not ios6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable the `autolayout` in your xib's file inspector.

[image: autolayout]

Check this [autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) tutorial for resolving the issues, without disabling it.

Comment: I just want to disable it because I am using a different storyboard for iphone 5

Comment: @OnkaPlonka: ok, then you can use the above method. Disable the autolayout for that xib.

Answer (score 3):

Go to nib open attribute inspector go to first tab scroll down you can see auto layout option

there uncheck that checkbox. See image do same like as:

[image]