# Use old AutoLayout in new XCode Projects?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xib, autolayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove autolayout (constraints) in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder)
>   While the answer and final question are the same, the rest of the questions are completely different and the questions that appeared when I searched were unrelated to either question.

In my app, I am trying to set the autoLayout to setup my view properly for iPhone 4 screen size versus the iPhone 5 screensize.  With the kind of layout I am dealing with, I really don't need the power provided by the new constraints system and it would be much easier to use the old system.  I know this is possible because the older xib files in my project use the old system.

My question is: How do I use the old system in new xib files?

Comment: Go to file inspector & untick AutoLayout option...& then check.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567) for an animated GIF showing you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your xib file in Xcode, open the right-side pane, select the 1st tab in it, and unselect the "Use auto layout" checkbox.