# Unable to move UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder, uistoryboard

In an XCode iPad application, I use a storyboard with a view and an UIImageView inside, defined in the Interface Builder.
If I try to change the location of the UIImageView using the SetFrame command [myImageView setFrame:CgRectMake...], the image does not change position on the screen.
Is the setFrame command enough ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder

Comment: See if you connected the outlets , also check for Auto-Layout disbaled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go through a checklist and see that the setup is good:

1. **Check your IBOutlet** - if your UIImageView isn't hooked up, nothing you try calling on it will work.
2. **Check the autoresize mask** - If this is a non-trivial layout where some views are nested within one another, there might be unexpected results.
3. **Make sure you're not using Autolayout** - This can be done by selecting the storyboard itself and making sure the "Use Autolayout" checkbox within the file inspector (cmd+alt+1) is not ticked (Ticked by default).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but does the UIImageView need to be redrawn after you change it's location as this is often the case in programming?