# Unchecking AutoLayout does not format subviews properly

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

I have an iphone app that contains xib with "Use AutoLayOut" as checked.But building that app in iphone 5.0 simulator getting the app crasged due to "NSLayoutConstraint".

As autolayout not there in ios5 unchecked autolayout and the app runs on iphone5 simulator wiyh out crashing but the subviews present in that viewcontroller are not formatting properly.

Is there any way to do this .

Comment: Because you [haven't done any research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder) before asking your question. You simply could layout the traditional non-auto-layout way and fix things up by looking at the results in the simulator.

Comment: am unchecking the autolayout for compatibility with ios5.0 but subviews in that view not displaying properly and functioning also

Answer (score 0):

if you create any xib in iso 6.0 or above means xcode(4.5.x) and above then you get Constraint in xib.
like :

[image: Xib]

if want to run it in lower version then please unchecked Use AutoLayout chkeckbox. in Xib
select FilesOwner->ShowFileInspector ->

[image: unchecked Use AutoLayout]

if you unchecked it then it will run on ios5 and its lowerversion.

Comment: yes,am unchecking autolayout but i subviews in that viewcontroller are not displaying properly and button click events also

Comment: autolayout for all my subviews are unchecked