# How can I delete the Xcode constraints?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to `Mavericks` and installed `Xcode 5.0.1`.
I opened one of my projects, which targets 10.6, and declined the option to upgrade to "Upgrade to take advantage of Xcode 5 features?" which mentioned Auto layout.

Now 2 of my xib files have errors (the other 12 seem OK):-

```
error: Illegal Configuration: Auto Layout on OS X prior to 10.7
warning: Attribute Unavailable: Identifier on OS X versions prior to 10.7
Attribute Unavailable: Automatically Recalculates Cell Size on OS X versions prior to 10.8 - 0n NSMatrix
```

How can I delete the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566789/remove-autolayout-constraints-in-interface-builder)

You need to disable autolayout for the NIB completely since 10.6 doesn't support it at all.

If disabling autolayout doesn't clear the other two warnings, you should be able to click the "!" warning symbol to be taken to the offending setting. Looks like a couple of checkboxes simply need to be unchecked.